# Magento2 | Listing grid / "select all" option not working

Tags: admin, magento2.2, grid, uicomponent, select

I’m having issue building listing grid in my own module.
The fact is that if I select one or severals checkboxes, it works. If I select all (one by one or using the select all dropdown above), nothing change. No delete and no confirm message.

After searchs, the parameter « selected » is sent correctly but the array with the id selected is empty.
Do you know why and how to fix it ?

Magento CE : 2.2.5

Sources files :

uiComponent

```
<!-- main part of the grid -->
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <!-- define where to find the date source -->
    <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">maroute2_page_listing.maroute2_page_listing_data_source</item>
        <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">maroute2_page_listing.maroute2_page_listing_data_source</item>
    </item>
    <!-- define where to find the columns -->
    <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">maroute2_page_columns</item>

    <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add a new Contact</item>
            <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
            <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/Add</item>
        </item>
    </item>
</argument>

<!-- define the date source (must be the same than in argument/item/provider and argument/js_config/deps -->
<dataSource name="maroute2_page_listing_data_source">
    <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
        <!-- unique name for the grid -->
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">ContactsGridDataProvider</argument>
        <!-- name of the data source same as in argument/js_config/provider -->
        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">maroute2_page_listing_data_source</argument>
        <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">toto_contacts_id</argument>
        <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">toto_contacts_id</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </argument>
</dataSource>

<!-- define the columns of my grid -->
<columns name="maroute2_page_columns">

    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <!-- Bookmarks behaviour -->
            <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">maroute2_page_listing.maroute2_page_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current</item>
            </item>
            <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="controlVisibility" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">maroute2_page_listing.maroute2_page_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="root" xsi:type="string">columns.${ $.index }</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.${ $.storageConfig.root}</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>

    <selectionsColumn name="ids">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <!-- define which field will be used as ID -->
                <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">toto_contacts_id</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </selectionsColumn>

    <!-- Column ID -->
    <column name="toto_contacts_id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <!-- Column name -->
    <column name="name">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">contact</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">name</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Name</item>
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <!-- Column email -->
    <column name="email">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">contact</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">email</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Email</item>
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <!-- action columns edit and delete -->
    <actionsColumn name="actions" class="toto\Helloworld\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\ContactsActions">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">107</item>
                <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">toto_contacts_id</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </actionsColumn>
</columns>

<!-- optionnel -->
<container name="listing_top">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/toolbar</item>
        </item>
    </argument>

    <!-- we put the others elements here -->
    <container name="columns_controls">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="columnsData" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">maroute2_page_listing.maroute2_page_listing.maroute2_page_columns</item>
                </item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/columns</item>
                <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridActions</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </container>

    <bookmark name="bookmarks">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/bookmarks/bookmarks</item>
                <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridActions</item>
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="saveUrl" xsi:type="url" path="*/*/save"/>
                    <item name="deleteUrl" xsi:type="url" path="*/*/delete"/>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">maroute2_page_listing</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </bookmark>

    <paging name="listing_paging">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <!-- we put here the path to the bookmarks element -->
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">maroute2_page_listing.maroute2_page_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.paging</item>
                </item>
                <!-- we put here the path to the element pfay_contact_ids of contacts_test_columns  element -->
                <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">maroute2_page_listing.maroute2_page_listing.maroute2_page_columns.toto_contacts_id</item>
                <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">bottom</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </paging>

    <filters name="listing_filters">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">maroute2_page_listing.maroute2_page_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">curren.filters</item>
                </item>
                <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">maroute2_page_listing.maroute2_page_listing.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                    <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="visible" xsi:type="string">maroute2_page_listing.maroute2_page_listing.listing_top.bookmarks:current.columns.${ $.index }.visible</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </filters>

    <massaction name="listing_massaction">
         <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
             <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                 <!-- we put here the path to the element pfay_contact_ids of contacts_test_columns  element -->
                 <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">maroute2_page_listing.maroute2_page_listing.maroute2_page_columns.ids</item>
                 <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">bottom</item>
                 <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">toto_contacts_id</item>
             </item>
         </argument>
         <action name="delete">
             <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                 <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                     <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                     <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete Selected</item>
                     <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="*/*/massDelete"/>
                     <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                         <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete all selected contacts</item>
                         <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Do you want to delete all the selected contacts?</item>
                     </item>
                 </item>
             </argument>
         </action>
     </massaction>

     <!-- Filter Search -->
     <filterSearch name="fulltext">
         <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
             <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                 <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">maroute2_page_listing.maroute2_page_listing_data_source</item>
                 <item name="chipsProvider" xsi:type="string">maroute2_page_listing.maroute2_page_listing.listing_top.listing_filters_chips</item>
                 <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                     <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">maroute2_page_listing.maroute2_page_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                     <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.search</item>
                 </item>
             </item>
         </argument>
     </filterSearch>

</container>
```

MassDelete controller

```
class MassDelete extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action {
public function execute() {
    $ids = $this->getRequest()->getParam('selected', []);

    //var_dump($ids);
    //exit;

    if (!is_array($ids) || !count($ids)) {
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/index', array('_current' => true));
    }

    foreach ($ids as $id) {
        if ($contact = $this->_objectManager->create(Contact::class)->load($id)) {
            $contact->delete();
        }
    }
    $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('A total of %1 record(s) have been deleted.', count($ids)));

    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
    return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/index', array('_current' => true));
}}
```

[image: 1]]
/***********************/
Edit 09-06-2018

See below the output when I do a $ids = $this->getRequest()->getParams() and both cases :

//select one or many

```
array (size=6)
  'key' => string '3facf2af98e5da6519aff1da3ed860651e446b4a51640f3f4db86d43a9ac50a4' (length=64)
    'selected' => 
      array (size=2)
        0 => string '10' (length=2)
        1 => string '9' (length=1)
    'filters' => 
      array (size=1)
        'placeholder' => string 'true' (length=4)
    'search' => string '' (length=0)
    'namespace' => string 'maroute2_page_listing' (length=21)
    'form_key' => string 'DbgFSakzdi1xLujW' (length=16)
```

//select all

```
array (size=6)
  'key' => string '3facf2af98e5da6519aff1da3ed860651e446b4a51640f3f4db86d43a9ac50a4' (length=64)
  'excluded' => string 'false' (length=5)
  'filters' => 
    array (size=1)
      'placeholder' => string 'true' (length=4)
  'search' => string '' (length=0)
  'namespace' => string 'maroute2_page_listing' (length=21)
  'form_key' => string 'DbgFSakzdi1xLujW' (length=16)
```

> An array of selected/excluded elements applied filters and applied full-text search terms are sent there. The difference between the transmitted parameters depends on the method of selection. If you press "select all", the element "excluded" contains "false". If you have chosen a few elements manually, the array "selected" contains the entity id of all selected records. If you press "select all", but later uncheck several records manually, the array
>   "excluded" contains the entity id of all unchecked records. To see an example of the implementation of "massDelete" action and how these parameters are processed, look at the class Magento\Cms\Controller\Adminhtml\Block\massDelete.

https://www.gomage.com/blog/uigrid/

Comment: Looks, like there was an issue in your admin grid, as shown in screenshot, massaction and other filter is on bottom which is not a standard admin grid.

Comment: Hum thanks for warning ;) I think tutorial was a little bit old. massaction and other filter was defined in last position in the ui_component xml file with options that no needed any more. And I was using <container> instead of <listingToolbar>. After modify this, page looks like a standard admin grid ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.You need to create MassDelete.php file in your controller.

```
<?php
    namespace Namespace\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Order;

    use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
    use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
    use Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter;
    use WilliamsCommerce\OrderBy\Model\ResourceModel\OrderBy\CollectionFactory;

    /**
     * Class MassDelete
     */
    class MassDelete extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
    {
        /**
         * @var Filter
         */
        protected $filter;

        /**
         * @var CollectionFactory
         */
        protected $collectionFactory;

        /**
         * @param Context $context
         * @param Filter $filter
         * @param CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
         */
        public function __construct(Context $context, Filter $filter, CollectionFactory $collectionFactory)
        {
            $this->filter = $filter;
            $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
            parent::__construct($context);
        }

        /**
         * Execute action
         *
         * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect
         * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException|\Exception
         */
        public function execute()
        {
            $collection = $this->filter->getCollection($this->collectionFactory->create());
            $collectionSize = $collection->getSize();

            foreach ($collection as $page) {
                $page->delete();
            }
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('A total of %1 record(s) have been deleted.', $collectionSize));

            /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
        }
    }
```

This code will delete your selected rows and all mass delete as well.

Comment: welcome if helpful then vote will help to other guys.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your massdelete controller

use this

> $ids = $this->getRequest()->getParam('ids');

Hope it helps

Comment: Hey John, thanks for your help. Unfortunately, getParam('ids') return a null value when you select all checkboxes (and one or many)